# Calculation of first correction to Selberg type integral

Tags: real-analysis, lie-groups, integration, haar-measure

$\DeclareMathOperator\U{U}\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}\DeclareMathOperator\Tr{Tr}\DeclareMathOperator\arcsinh{arcsinh}$Let $U \in G$, where $G$  is $\SU(N)$  matrix.
$\Tr U$ will denote the character of the fundamental representation of
$G$ and $dU$ — the normalized (reduced) Haar measure on $G$.
We evaluate the following integral over $G$ in the large $N$ limit
\begin{equation}
Z_G(h) \ = \ \int_G dU \ \exp \left [ \frac{N h}{2} \left ( \Tr  U
+ \Tr  U^{\dagger}  \right )   \right  ] = \sum_{q=-\infty}^{\infty} \det I_{i-j+q} (N h)\ .
\label{Gint_def}
\end{equation}
In practice it is somewhat simpler to compute $Z_N(h)$ by the saddle-point method when $h$ is large. Parametrizing $\SU(N)$ matrices through its eigenvalues one obtains
\begin{equation}
Z_N(h)   \ = \ \sum_{q=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{N!}
\int_0^{2\pi}\prod_{i=1}^N \frac{d\omega_i}{2\pi} \ \prod_{i<j} 4 \sin^2\left ( \frac{\omega_i - \omega_j}{2} \right )
\ e^{N  h \sum_{i=1}^N\cos\omega_i + iq\sum_{i=1}^N \omega_i }  \ .
\label{sun_integral_param}
\end{equation}
Expanding the integrand around non-trivial saddle-point $\omega_k= x_0 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \varpi_k  = -i\arcsinh \frac{q}{N h}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \varpi_k$ where we taking   $q= x/N $ yields
\begin{eqnarray}
Z_N(h)\  = \ \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^N N!} \int_0^{\infty} d x \  e^{N^2( \sqrt{h^2+x^2} -  x \arcsinh\frac{x}{h})}\times \\
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} d^N \varpi
\prod_{i<j} ( \varpi_i - \varpi_j )^2
e^{ N \sum_{i=1}^N (-\frac{1}{2 x} h \cos x_0  \varpi_i^2 + \frac{1}{6 x^{3/2}} h \sin x_0  \varpi_i ^3+ \frac{1}{24 x^2} h \cos x_0 \varpi_i^4 + O(1/x^{5/2}))+  \eta_i \varpi_i} = K \times \prod_{i=1}^N\left[1 + \frac{i x }{6 N^{1/2} (x^2+h^2)^{3/4}}   (\frac{\partial }{\partial \eta_i })^3+ \frac{1}{24 N \sqrt{x^2+h^2}} (\frac{\partial }{\partial \eta_i } )^4 + ... \right] e^{ \frac{ x}{2 N \sqrt{x^2+h^2}} \eta_i \eta_i}  \ .
\label{sun_integral_selberg}
\end{eqnarray}
The integral obtained is of the Selberg type. Using the paper "[The importance of the Selberg integral](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0273-0979-08-01221-4)" of
P. Forrester, O. Warnaar, Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society
**45** (2008) 489,  one finds
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\det I_{i-j+q} (N h) \ \simeq \ K = \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{\frac{N}{2}}} \
\frac{G(N+1)}{N^{\frac{1}{2}N^2}}  \nonumber \\
&&\exp \left \{ N^2 \left [ \sqrt{h^2 + x^2}  -
x \ln \left ( \frac{x}{h} + \sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{h^2}}  \right ) - \frac{1}{4} \ \ln (h^2 + x^2) + O(1/h) \right ]  \right \} \ .
\label{detsun_as}
\end{eqnarray}
As we see true expansion is did by powers $1/\sqrt{h^2+x^2}$.

How to find at least first correction to main contribution?

Comment: Ok , I fix it .

Comment: Is it ok right now?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441258/calculation-of-first-correction-to-selberg-type-integral#comment1138343_441258), I really think you just mean "where $G = \operatorname{SU}(N)$".  But the meaning is probably clear anyway.